# Delphi - Comparing two pathnames when one is UNC and one is drive letter-specified

Tags: delphi, path, directory-structure, delphi-2006, unc

I have a situation where a user can specify two separate pathnames, and I need to check whether one pathname is "inside" the other one.  I can do this if both pathnames are UNC, or both are drive-letter-based, but what if they are mixed?

Can you "normalise" a path such as "C:\Program Files" to "\\[this computer name]\C\Program Files"?  Obviously, I can't go the other way, as a network folder in UNC format may not have a corresponding drive letter mapped to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [ExpandUNCFileName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExpandUNCFileName) function.

Comment: +1 Also the [WNetGetUniversalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can help too.

Comment: (@RRUZ, isn't `ExpandUNCFileName` a wrapper for `WNetGetUniversalName`, or can you learn more with that call?) I had erroneously thought that `ExpandUNCFilename` didn't work in all cases, but a bit of more thorough testing shows that if `ExpandUNCFileName` doesn't return a name starting with ` \\ ` its because it's a local drive.  So one path can't be inside the other if either of their `ExpandUNCFileName`'d versions start with a drive letter.

Comment: Yes the `ExpandUNCFileName ` calls the `WNetGetUniversalName` function but with the `UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL` flag, you can use this function with the `REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL` value too. So you can build a more complete solution using directly the NetGetUniversalName function.