# Identify if a drive letter is a local or network drive?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, network-drive, drive-letter

I'm working on a utility which has an input for a shared folder. My app requires that the folder selected is on a remote computer, and not on the local computer. I would like to recognize if the user selects `C:\` from the local computer as opposed to `Z:\` which is probably a network drive. How do I validate this?

Comment: See [Serg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458991/576719) to the question [Delphi - Comparing two pathnames when one is UNC and one is drive letter-specified](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10458753/576719). [ExpandUNCFileName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExpandUNCFileName). This function returns network drives starting with \\

Comment: Good trick, I've summed it up to `IsNetworkPath := Pos('\\', ExpandUNCFileName(APath)) = 1;`

Comment: Its should be noted that GetDriveType will return DRIVE_REMOTE, and ExpandUncFileName will return a result starting with '\\' for a drive created with SUBST on the local computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you need is [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: ... with result `DRIVE_REMOTE`, that'll do it!